# DbGeography Intersects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbgeography

I'm using `DbGeography` with `Entity Framework 6` using this model:

```
public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public DbGeography Area { get; set; }

}
```

I'm then trying to execute the `Intersects` method like below:

```
public County GetCurrentCounty(double latitude, double longitude)
{  
    var point = DbGeography.PointFromText(
        "POINT("
        + longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " "
        + latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ")",
        4326);

    var area = db.Counties.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        point.Intersects(x.Area));


    var area1 = db.Counties.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        x.Area.Intersects(point));
}
```

However the query created looks like this for both methods. Is there something I can do to not select the entire table and perform a query in the database instead?

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Extent1].[Area] AS [Area]
    FROM [Election].[County] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this query. `FirstOrDefault` should be translated to `SELECT TOP (1)...` Did you use `Database.Log` handler to log this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say what the error was but the second time it showed the correct values. T-SQL generated by Entity Framework:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
[Extent1].[Area] AS [Area]
FROM [Election].[County] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Area].STIntersects(@p__linq__0)) = 1


-- p__linq__0: 'POINT (10.0000000 32.0000000)' (Type = Object)
```

Can be tested like this manually:

```
declare @p__linq__0 varchar(max)
set @p__linq__0 = 'POINT (10.0000000 32.0000000)' 

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Extent1].[Area] AS [Area]
    FROM [Election].[County] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Area].STIntersects(@p__linq__0)) = 1
```

More information can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type